# Cherry blossoms and cross-pollination

Tags: trees, cherries

Can cherry blossoms be used to cross pollinate sweet cherry trees?

I recently got two Royal Ann cherry trees to plant in my yard. After planting them, I noticed on the card that came with the trees that they require a pollinator. I did some research online and learned that sweet cherry trees need to have another type of cherry tree nearby to cross pollinate to set cherries. I did not know that and the staff at the nursery did not share that info with me. My neighborhood has a lot cherry blossoms, I was wondering if they can help the cross pollination process. I found a chart online that only show cross pollination across sweet cherry trees.

Here's an example: link is dead, removed

Comment: Welcome! Could you please elaborate a bit? What exactly are you planning to do?

Comment: anything can pollinate anything, it just might not work like a weed is a plant just in the wrong place.

Comment: I edited my post to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful! How close (roughly) are the trees in your neighborhood? Gut feeling: if you have “lots”, That might be enough already.

Comment: Fairly close, the closest is probably maybe less than 10 meters (~30 feet) away. There are others a bit further away too. Do you think that it's enough?